# Counting the number of permutations of a finite sequence of numbers so that no number occurs in the same position

Tags: combinatorics

I came across this problem indirectly...

Say you have a finite sequence of numbers. Now you want to count how many
permutations there are of those numbers but so that no number occurs in
the same position, i.e. for example for 1,2,3 we have 2,3,1 and 3,1,2.

This question seems relevant to group theory for counting the number of 
possible groups for a finite set of elements as the multiplications tables
of finite groups do not have 'repeats' of elements in rows or columns...

Comment: Please see Wikipedia, *Derangements* (combinatorics).

Comment: Are you looking for the number of permutations such that (a) each number appears in each position exactly once, or (b) a number $n$ can appear in any position any amount of times, except for the $n$th position? If (a) the answer is quite straightforward.

Comment: The generalization of a group that you are describing is a Latin square. There is a lot of literature on this.

Comment: You are looking for all the permutations having no cycle of length 1.

Comment: Also known as the secretary's problem, or the envelope problem. If a secretary puts n  different letters into n envelopes, one letter per envelope, addressed to n different recipients, what are the odds P(n)  that nobody gets the right letter? Your Q's answer is n!P(n). The formula is $P(n)=\sum_{j=0}^{j=n}(-1)^j/j!.$ Induction can help to get this.